# Find min/max values in a dataframe containing a mixture of integers and strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, integer, nan

I have a data frame which columns a, b, c contain integers and strings like this:

```
a    | b    | c
0.82 | 1.17 | 2.05
0.02 | ND   | ND
2.00 | 1.08 | 0.02*
```

I need to find the min/max values for each row and populate new fourth/fifth columns titled "Min"/"Max" with the respective values, while considering ND as a minimum value. I can find the first row's min/max values with

```
df.loc[["a", "b", "c"]].min(axis=1) 
#and max(axis=1)
```

and work for the second with

```
df.loc[((data["a"].isin(["ND"])) | (data["b"].isin(["ND"])) |
       (data["c"].isin(["ND"])), "Min"] = "ND"
```

but have no idea what I should do for the third row's 0.02*. I need to do a comparison of the integers but maintain value when I populate the "Min" column, so the end result would look like

```
a    | b    | c     | Min   | Max
0.82 | 1.17 | 2.05  | 0.82  | 2.05
0.02 | ND   | ND    | ND    | 0.02
2.00 | 1.08 | 0.02* | 0.02* | 2
```

I have over 200 values with the * in my entire data frame so manual replacement isn't an option. I considered removing the * first but am not sure how I would restore them when I have to populate the min/max columns.

If anyone has a workaround for this any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like in these columns, you're comparing strings lexicographically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to do some housekeeping on your data. A couple of `df.replace` calls should do it:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace('ND', np.nan)\
           .replace('\*', '', regex=True).astype(float)
print(df)

      a     b     c
0  0.82  1.17  2.05
1  0.02   NaN   NaN
2   2.0  1.08  0.02
```

Now, apply `max` and `min`:

```
df['Max'] = df.max(1)
df['Min'] = df.min(1)

print(df)

      a     b     c   Max   Min
0  0.82  1.17  2.05  2.05  0.82
1  0.02   NaN   NaN  0.02  0.02
2  2.00  1.08  0.02  2.00  0.02
```

---

An update, based on your constraints:

```
dftemp = df.astype(str).replace('ND', -np.inf)\
               .replace('\*', '', regex=True).astype(float)    
df['Max'] = dftemp.max(1)
df['Min'] = dftemp.min(1).replace(-np.inf, 'ND')      

print(df)    
      a     b      c   Max   Min
0  0.82  1.17   2.05  2.05  0.82
1  0.02    ND     ND  0.02    ND
2   2.0  1.08  0.02*  2.00  0.02
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this method, as specified in my original post. I need ND to be minimum values and need to keep the * in my max/min columns.

Comment: Replace 'ND' with -np.inf instead of np.nan?

Comment: You may keep the *. But you remove it when computing the min-max.

Comment: @PeterKwon Well, updated based on your weird requests.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your solution works for the posted question, my thanks for that. Now the problem is the solution clashes with other variables in the data frame...such is life.

Comment: @PeterKwon It's simple dude. Just use `df.iloc` and work with subslices. Don't sweat the details :)